# Can't set values in localStorage in desktop Safari

Tags: safari

When trying to set values in localStorage in desktop safari I receive a `QuotaExceededError (DOM Exception 22): The quota has been exceeded.` error. localStorage is empty and this is *not* in a private browsing window. Is there a setting or option somewhere for Safari which disables localStorage?

Comment: Just trying clearing all website data (via the privacy settings), even with everything cleared out I still get the QuotaExceededError

Comment: Also tried on different sites, same problem everywhere

Comment: Not sure what the issue was but I followed the instructions at https://www.macissues.com/2015/06/22/how-to-fully-reset-safari-on-your-mac/ to completely reset safari. This must mean that there is in fact a setting somewhere which allows you to disable localStorage.